# The intersection of ordered pairs.2

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Definition of (a,b) is the set {{a},{a,b}}.
Of course, (a,b) intersection with (b,a)
is the set {{a,b}}. But if we represent ordered pairs as points in a plane, they do not intersect. Please explain.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/857616/the-intersection-of-ordered-pairs

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that I wrote a computer program in some high-level language (e.g. C, or Java, or Delphi) and I declare that **StrName** is a string variable. Then **StrName** is *not an integer*. But stored in memory the string is nothing but a sequence of bits, can't I treat this sequence as a number? Of course I can.

So while writing something like **StrName+2** is meaningless in the language that I've chosen, I can preform this sort of manipulation if I know how to treat the string as a number.

Similarly here. Set theory allows us to take mathematical objects and interpret them as sets. Therefore it makes sense to apply set operations on them. But this doesn't mean that these operations agree with the objects on their typical use. If $(a,b)$ is a point on the plane, it makes absolutely no sense to talk about $(a,b)\cap(b,a)$ because points on the plane are not sets, they are ordered pairs.

In fact, one can argue that points on the plane are not ordered pairs either. They can be represented as ordered pairs, and this representation is so good, that we are willing to forget that.

But this is besides the point. Does it make sense that ask $(a,b)\subseteq(a,b,c)$? Or $\varnothing\in(a,b)$? From a type theoretic point of view, no. It makes no sense to ask whether or not an ordered pair is a subset of an ordered triplet, or if the empty set is an element of an ordered pair. But if you interpret these objects as sets, then the questions make sense. The answers, however, need not make sense in the typical use.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to intersect two singleton subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  These should be interpreted as the subsets: $$A:=\{(a,b)\}=\left\{\big\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\big\}\right\}$$ and $$B:=\{(b,a)\}=\left\{\big\{\{b\},\{b,a\}\big\}\right\}.$$

Here, we have $A \cap B=\emptyset$ (assuming $a \neq b$), where there is no contradiction.

In the question, there is a contradiction since $(a,b) \cap (b,a)$ should not be interpreted as the intersection of the two points in the plane.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. A point on the plane is **NOT** the singleton whose element is that point.

Comment: Well, I certainly agree with the second part of that comment, i.e., $(a,b) \neq \{(a,b)\}$.  In this answer, I'm correcting the syntax error and showing that there's no contradiction.

Comment: But this is not a syntax error. The previous question by the OP, asked only moments before this one, was that $(a,b)\cap(b,a)=\{a,b\}$ (when interpreting an ordered pair using Kuratowski's definition of ordered pairs). And the OP specifically says that, in this post as well.